# Python - ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 48: given 8

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to show cumulative return on a graph with the following code:

## stock info

```
stocks = ['TD', 'RTN', 'DIS', 'NKE', 'TSLA', 'BYND', 'AMZN', 'MFC']

weights = [0.1409, 0.1572, 0.1124, 0.1449, 0.1619, 0.1022, 0.0296, 0.1509]

start = pd.to_datetime('2018-08-20')
end = dt.datetime.today()

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start, end)
print(data)
```

## cumulative return graph

```py
return_data = data.pct_change()[1:]
weighted_returns = (weights * return_data)
total_return = weighted_returns.sum(axis=1)
cumulative_return = (total_return + 1).cumprod()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
ax1.plot(cumulative_return)
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel("Returns")
ax1.set_title("Portfolio Cumulative Returns")
plt.show();
```

however I get this error: ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 48: given 8

Any help?

edit:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2c8173a96906> in <module>
      2 
      3 return_data = data.pct_change()[1:]
----> 4 weighted_returns = (weights * return_data)
      5 
      6 total_return = weighted_returns.sum(axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
   1486     def f(self, other, axis=default_axis, level=None, fill_value=None):
   1487 
-> 1488         other = _align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis)
   1489 
   1490         if isinstance(other, ABCDataFrame):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in _align_method_FRAME(left, right, axis)
   1456     elif is_list_like(right) and not isinstance(right, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame)):
   1457         # GH17901
-> 1458         right = to_series(right)
   1459 
   1460     return right

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in to_series(right)
   1417             if len(left.columns) != len(right):
   1418                 raise ValueError(
-> 1419                     msg.format(req_len=len(left.columns), given_len=len(right))
   1420                 )
   1421             right = left._constructor_sliced(right, index=left.columns)

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 48: given 8
```

Comment: can you share the entire stack trace?

Comment: @adrianp sorry I'm new to python; what do you mean by stack trace? the rest of the code?

Comment: on top of the `ValueError` line, you should see the lines in which the error took place. That's called Traceback or Stack Trace, depends on the language you're using. That would help us see where the problem took place.

Comment: @adrianp done. also added the lines relevant to the weights

Comment: seems like your `return_data` has 48 values while `weights` only has 8. Are you getting the right values for `return_data`?

Comment: @adrianp got it! ```data = data['Adj Close']``` I forgot to use the adjusted closing prices to refer back to the weights